# How Frenzapp gets the version of other apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, system-calls

Does anyone know how Frenzapp gets the *Version* of other installed apps?

They probably use sysctl to enumerate running processes which returns kinfo_proc struct for each process. Looking at kinfo_proc there is no version or file time stamps or anything I can associate with a version.

So I am wondering how they do it. Does anyone know?

Here is the screen shot with the app version:

[image: Here is the screen shot with the app version]

Answer (score 4):

It is not the version of the app currentlty installed on your device but the latest version available on the App Store, obtained through iTunes API.

Erwan (creator of Frenzapp)